# How to forward signals in a QAbstractItemModel wrapper model

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qabstractitemmodel

I intend to create my own item model, derived from QAbstractItemModel. The model does not contain data but wraps some data repository. That repository emits signals after item(s) are insert, removed, renamed, etc.

Whenever something changes in the repository, my item model needs to forward those signals.

However the repository has standalone signals like `void itemRemoved(int index);` while QAbstractItemModel has begin/end pairs of protected functions (and signals) like `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()`.

How should I handle this? E.g. I could connect a slot like the following to the repository's `itemRemoved()` signal:

```
void RepositoryItemRemoved(int i)
{
   beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), i, i);
   endInsertRows();
}
```

Based on the above example: Is it valid to call `beginInsertRows()` / `endInsertRows()` sequently *after* a row has been inserted in the repository?

Comment: Do you have any idea what side effects could happen due to not following the intended use?

Comment: To be honest, this design doesn't make much sense to me. A single signal after the data insert or remove should be enough to do the job. It may only be problematic in a mutilthreaded context, but then a simple mutex would do the trick. I might be missing something, but I've had many cases where Qt internals are designed sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar scenario, where the data is in a different object, and the model is just a wrapper, and only created if that data set is displayed in a view. I used a pointer to the model object in the data object, checking if it is null on insert operations, and if not call `beginInsertRows()` and  `endInsertRows()` through it. Naturally, since those are protected, the data class would have to be declared a friend to the model class.

The documentation stresses that it is important to call `beginInsertRows()` before any data is inserted:

> When reimplementing insertRows() in a subclass, you must call this
>   function before inserting data into the model's underlying data store...
>
> ...Otherwise, the views may end up in an invalid state.

You should test with a view, or alternatively, examine the actual implementation in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I've had somewhat similar scenario as well, only in my case the Qt model wrapped the underlying model a little more literally: the underlying model contained sufficiently more data than the view had to know about. So I let the Qt model to contain its own list of small pieces of each underlying model's data item for the view/delegate to deal with. So the slots processing the updates from the underlying model looked like this:

```
void RepositoryItemRemoved(int i)
{
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), i, i);
    removeModelItem(i);
    endRemoveRows();
}
```

Such design solved the problem of view's invalid state although it may be impractical for the use cases in which letting the Qt model contain its own items list would mean duplicating the sufficient amount of data being worked with.